# oracle "merge into" too slow

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-merge

i'm trying to update a column in a table using the id of another table only if one or two field match each other. Sadly the query run very slowly and i don't understand why.
PS:(the checked fields for table A may be null or have leading/trailing empty spaces )

```
MERGE INTO B B1
USING (
    SELECT B2.LUSERINVENTORYID LUSERINVENTORYID, a1.lastid lastid
      FROM B B2,
           (SELECT lastid,
                   TRIM(UPPER(serialno)) AS serialno,
                   TRIM(UPPER(barcode)) AS barcode
              FROM A) a1
     WHERE (B2.loaded_serialno = a1.serialno AND B2.loaded_barcode = a1.barcode) 
        OR (B2.loaded_serialno = a1.serialno AND  B2.loaded_barcode IS NULL) 
        OR (B2.loaded_serialno IS NULL       AND  B2.loaded_barcode = a1.barcode) 
   ) res
ON (B1.luserinventoryid = res.luserinventoryid)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET B1.lassetinvolvedid = res.lastid
```

please somebody can tell me how i can improve the execution time of this merge?

Comment: Why do you need an extra subquery for the table `A` ? Do you have indexes on the columns which takes place after `WHERE` and `ON` clauses ?

Comment: There's no `lastid` column in your query and you cannot update a table that is not a target of the `merge` (`B1`). Please provide complete reproducible example along with an execution plan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without looking at your execution plan or knowing your data, we can only guess. That being said, at first glance I can tell you that you are almost certain to have problems stemming from those OR clauses in your join.  If you can rewrite this to use a definite join column instead of all these conditions, you'll be much better off.

If you can't, you may also try the hint /*+ use_concat */ and Oracle might rewrite it as three UNION ALL sets with a single-column definite join in each one, which is basically rewriting it for you.

```
MERGE INTO b b1
USING (
        SELECT /*+ use_concat */ b2.id id, a1.id lastid
          FROM b b2,
               (SELECT a1.id,
                       TRIM(UPPER(a1.serialno)) AS serialno,
                       TRIM(UPPER(a1.barcode)) AS barcode
                  FROM a) a1
         WHERE (b2.loaded_serialno = a1.serialno AND b2.loaded_barcode = a1.barcode) 
            OR (b2.loaded_serialno = a1.serialno AND  b2.loaded_barcode IS NULL) 
            OR (b2.loaded_serialno IS NULL       AND  b2.loaded_barcode = a1.barcode) 
       ) res
  ON (a1.luserinventoryid = res.luserinventoryid)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET b1.lassetinvolvedid = res.lastid;
```

Answer (score 0):

Without your data it is difficult to determine but you appear to perform a self-join on `B` in the `ON` clause of the merge and if there is a 1-to-1 correspondence (i.e. you are joining on a field with a `UNIQUE` key) then you could possibly skip that and merge `A` and `B` directly:

```sql
MERGE INTO B
USING (
  SELECT lastid,
         TRIM(UPPER(serialno)) AS serialno,
         TRIM(UPPER(barcode)) AS barcode
  FROM   A
) A
ON (  (B.loaded_serialno = a.serialno AND B.loaded_barcode = a.barcode) 
   OR (B.loaded_serialno = a.serialno AND B.loaded_barcode IS NULL) 
   OR (B.loaded_serialno IS NULL      AND B.loaded_barcode = a.barcode)
   )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET B.lassetinvolvedid = A.lastid;
```